# Rails namespaces and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I need help. I want administration for my rails application. I tried to set the routes with namespaces, but namespaces require a resource, and resource must have id in get request.

Anybody know how to set up correctly? I using windows machine. Thanks.

My routes :

```
Web::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin do
    resources :access # GET http://localhost/admin/access/login/login - stupid??
  end

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `resource :access` instead of `resources :access`

```
  namespace :admin do
    resource :access
  end
```

It will generate routes:

```
         admin_access POST   /admin/access(.:format)                                admin/access#create
          new_admin_access GET    /admin/access/new(.:format)                            admin/access#new
         edit_admin_access GET    /admin/access/edit(.:format)                           admin/access#edit
                              GET    /admin/access(.:format)                                admin/access#show
                              PUT    /admin/access(.:format)                                admin/access#update
                              DELETE /admin/access(.:format)                                admin/access#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  namespace :admin do
    get "login" => "access#login", :as => :login # GET http://localhost/admin/login - admin_login_path 
  end
```

Comment: Yes, but this is only for login method. I need for controllers like resource

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a set of *restful resources*, but just want a set of different controller methods, here's one way you can do it:

```
scope '/admin' do
  get '' => "admin#index", :as => 'admin_home'
  get '/users' => 'admin#users', :as => 'admin_users'
  get '/other_admin_task' => 'admin#other_admin_task', :as => 'other_admin_task'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way is only for method, I need for all method and controller like resource

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying. You can add as many routes to this as you need for whatever purpose you want. Whichever routes you want -- you just add them.