# Prefixing Route Controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Is there any way to prefix the controller path in `routes.rb`, so I don't have to specify it manually?

---

**Before:**

```rb
resources :users, :controller => 'api/users'
```

**After:**

```rb
resources :users, :controller => 'api/users'
```

**Or after:**

```rb
resources :users
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails namespaces and routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686697/rails-namespaces-and-routing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
```

[guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Just tried that before I wrote... Finally, a typo was the wrong guy.